# Help connecting a pendant light

Tags: ceiling, light

I bought a pendant lamp only has 1 blue and 1 green wire how do I connect to my ceiling that has ground, black and white wires ?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What's the make and model of the lamp? What do the instructions say?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the end of the pendant lamp and the inside of the ceiling box?

Comment: Your home wire colors imply North America 120V wiring. The lamp wire colors imply another country, probably 240V. Does the lamp take a 120 volt bulb?

Comment: There's no obvious place in the world where the [wiring colours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_wiring#Colour_code) allow blue + green to include a live/hot/phase wire. Are you sure there isn't a brown wire there somewhere? Can you check continuity from contacts in bulb-holder to each wire?

Comment: Better yet, post the brand and model number of the lamp.